# Tomcat URL Servlet Mapping

Tags: servlets, tomcat7

I have a sevelet with mapping like

```
<servlet-mapping>
      <servlet-name>Inventory</servlet-name>
      <url-pattern>/inventory</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

I would like to create a url mapping to /invlist that goes to /inventory?q=list

Comment: Your requirement is not clear. Can you provide more information?. Do you want to map  /inventory?q=list to Inventory servelet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<servlet-mapping>` only maps a Servlet to a URL but cannot map a URL to URL.

You need to create another Servlet for `/invlist` and in this Servlet , redirect to `/inventory?q=list` using [HttpServletResponse#sendRedirect](https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse.html#sendRedirect-java.lang.String-)

```
<servlet-mapping>
      <servlet-name>Inventory</servlet-name>
      <url-pattern>/inventory</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<servlet-mapping>
      <servlet-name>InventoryList</servlet-name>
      <url-pattern>/invlist</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Then in the InventoryList Servlet :

```
httpServletResponse.sendRedirect("inventory?q=list")
```